# Insert into elasticsearch with an id that contains slashes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, openfeign

Hello I am trying to insert an object into elasticsearch using it's API, the problem is that the IDs of elements that I want to insert are like this : `ee5z4d5/54zd15zd/5zd45`

when I sent a post request to `host/index/id` with a `body`, I got an error because the request url is `host/index/ee5z4d5/54zd15zd/5zd45`

I am using spring boot with feign client to comminucate with elasticsearch, and my question is how I can solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tldr;

This is not an Elastic issue but more a web issue.

What you need to do, is [encode the special char in the url](https://developers.google.com/maps/url-encoding).

Look at the solution below to find out what it means.

## Solution

```
POST /73690410/_doc/ee5z4d5%2F54zd15zd%2F5zd45
{
  "data": "my id has some slash"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to [URL-encode](https://www.urlencoder.org/) your ID first, i.e. the URL must look like this

```
host/index/ee5z4d5%2F54zd15zd%2F5zd45
```

I don't know Feign but [this issue](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/1190) might provide some insights on how to solve your issue.

Comment: could you check this question please ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73467506/elasticsearch-nested-phrase-search-within-a-distance